# How to repair this nmap error when doing scan with sudo?

Tags: linux, networking, nmap, port-scanning

im using nethunter on Termux. Anytime I try to perform -O scan on nmap it gives this error:
nmap: netutil.cc:3197: int route_dst_netlink(const sockaddr_storage*, route_nfo*, const char*, const sockaddr_storage*): Assertion `p != NULL' failed.

Aborted

But -sT scans work. Anytime it needs root privilages it doesnt work.
Thanks for helping me out
Best regards

I tried sudo apt upgrade nmap and it didnt help

Comment: This ia on Android right? You're not actually root in the Android OS, even if you `sudo`. You will need actual root permissions to make this work. So, a rooted device.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please include `--unprivileged` at end of your command, example:

```
nmap -v -A target.com --unprivileged
```